# Android wake lock is not released

Tags: android, release, wakelock

I get the wake lock like in `onCreate` method and it works fine (I also set the permissions):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Wake lock");
wl.acquire();
```

However, when I try to release it like:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    wl.release();
}
```

it is not released for some reason. How is this possible ? Any ideas ?

**EDIT**: I have an exit button which calls finish() which then calls onDestroy(). When I press the exit button and then put the phone to sleep I expect my program not to work but it works which shows me that the lock is not released

Comment: "it is not released for some reason" -- how have you determined this?

Comment: My app still works even when I put the phone to sleep (by pressing the sleep button)

Comment: What makes you think that `onDestroy()` is called when you "put the phone to sleep"?

Comment: I have an exit button which calls finish() which then calls onDestroy(). When I press the exit button and then put the phone to sleep I expect my program not to work but it works which shows me that the lock is not released

Comment: How do you know that your program still works even after onDestroy() was called?

Comment: "which shows me that the lock is not released" -- no, it does not. There are other apps on the device, any of which might be using a wakelock. Moreover, the device does not instantly fall asleep upon pressing the power button. Use `adb shell dumpsys power` to determine if you are holding a `WakeLock`.

Comment: Yes you are right there was something else holding the lock. Thanks so much for the info! Now if you could post your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to determine whether your `WakeLock`-releasing code works is to use `adb shell dumpsys power`, before and after the release, to see if your `WakeLock` is released. Since other apps can request and acquire `WakeLocks` whenever they want, other casual checks (e.g., does my app run when the screen is off?) will be unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

Change `release()` code to `onPause()` of the Activity. As per Android documentation, it is explained that to call acquire() in `onResume()` of Activity and release wakelock in `onPause()` of the Activity. In your case you are making the Activity sleep but not destroying it so it will not release the wakelock. So move it to `onPause()`.

Comment: I have an exit button which calls finish() which then calls onDestroy(). When I press the exit button and then put the phone to sleep I expect my program not to work. So its not the case that I press the sleep button while my program is running. Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. You can use `isHeld()` function to do it

```
 if (wl!= null && wl.isHeld()) {
    wl.release();
    wl= null;
 }
```